# Embedded NFS server doesn't support ver=2, but supports 1,3 - is this possible?

Tags: linux, nfs

My 2.6.37 Linux from MontaVista has NFS modules compiled. I start them sequentially as:

```
rpcbind
rpc.nfsd 4
rpc.mountd
rpc.statd
```

with default config files and etab as:

```
/mnt/sda1 192.168.50.0/24(rw,sync,wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,no_root_squash,no_all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,fsid=1,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534)
```

Everything works fine with my FC32 as a client:

```
[root@leonp mnt]# mount -v 192.168.1.1:/mnt/sda1/ srv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Aug  3 16:04:08 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.57'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,minorversion=1,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.57'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4,addr=192.168.1.1,clientaddr=192.168.1.57'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=192.168.1.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 39445
[root@leonp mnt]#
```

The problem starts when I try to connect with the client which supports NFSv2 only. So to test from PC:

```
[root@leonp mnt]# mount -vvv -o vers=2 192.168.1.1:/mnt/sda1/ srv
mount.nfs: timeout set for Mon Aug  3 13:50:14 2020
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=2,addr=192.168.1.1'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=2, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100003 vers 2 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=1, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.1.1 prog 100005 vers 1 prot UDP port 36357
mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported
mount.nfs: Protocol not supported
```

Why this? I checked:

```
[root@leonp mnt]# rpcinfo 192.168.1.1 
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100000    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    3    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    2    udp       0.0.0.0.0.111          portmapper superuser
    100000    4    local     /var/run/rpcbind.sock  portmapper superuser
    100000    3    local     /var/run/rpcbind.sock  portmapper superuser
    100003    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    2    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    3    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100021    1    udp       0.0.0.0.148.56         nlockmgr   unknown
    100021    3    udp       0.0.0.0.148.56         nlockmgr   unknown
    100021    4    udp       0.0.0.0.148.56         nlockmgr   unknown
    100021    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.228.206        nlockmgr   unknown
    100021    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.228.206        nlockmgr   unknown
    100021    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.228.206        nlockmgr   unknown
    100005    1    udp       0.0.0.0.142.5          mountd     superuser
    100005    1    tcp       0.0.0.0.130.95         mountd     superuser
    100005    2    udp       0.0.0.0.218.108        mountd     superuser
    100005    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.174.251        mountd     superuser
    100005    3    udp       0.0.0.0.154.21         mountd     superuser
    100005    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.132.150        mountd     superuser
```

The only one who does not support v2 is nlockmgr - can it be the cause of mount refusal?
To test this I tried to remove nlockmgr from running - no success. I tried to block it in /etc/rpc by commenting out 100021 - no success.

UPDATE:

```
#rcp.nfsd -d
rpc.nfsd: Checking netconfig for visible protocols.
rpc.nfsd: Enabling inet udp.
rpc.nfsd: Enabling inet tcp.
rpc.nfsd: knfsd is currently down
rpc.nfsd: Writing version string to kernel: +4.1 +2 +3 +4

#cat /proc/fs/nfsd/versions
+2 +3
============
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You need to adjust the NFS kernel server to offer version 2 (as you have noticed it no longer includes that by default). Running this on the server will allow you to test whether the proposed fix will work

```
rpc.nfsd 0 && sleep 1           # Stop all previous threads
rpc.nfsd --nfs-version 2,3 8    # Restart 8 threads with versions 2 and 3
```

If that works you need to make it permanent. On my Debian ("buster") system that still seems to involve editing `/etc/default/nfs-kernel-server`. On your system it will probably be different.

Original code

```
# Number of servers to start up
RPCNFSDCOUNT=32
```

Amended code

```
# Options and number of servers to start up
RPCNFSDCOUNT='--nfs-version 2,3 8'
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but this doesn't work in my case.
I receive "rpc.nfsd: unrecognized option '--nfs-version'
And the man page https://linux.die.net/man/8/rpc.nfsd acknowledge  what I suspected already to be correct - all compiled versions are supported. One can only command to exclude the specific version support.
Please, see the update too.

Comment: What does your own man page tell you about the version you've got installed?

Comment: The same:    
#rpc.nfsd --help      :    
Usage:
rpc.nfsd [-d|--debug] [-H hostname] [-p|-P|--port port] [-N|--no-nfs-version version ] [-s|
--syslog] [-T|--no-tcp] [-U|--no-udp] nrservs
```